# AngularJS: Using ngRepeat and ngModel with a checkbox is causing all checkboxes to become ticked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

My HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">

        <span ng-repeat="industry in ctrl.industryList">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="industry" ng-model="ctrl.oneIndustry" ng-change="ctrl.updateSelected(industry)">
        {{industry}}
      </label><br/>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am iterating through an array of industries and displaying a checkbox. When the checkbox is ticked, it is stored into an array. If the checkbox is then unticked, I would like to remove it from the array:

My Controller code:

```
vm.updateSelected = function (industry) {
    if (vm.oneIndustry) {

        vm.industries.push(industry)
    }
    else{
        vm.industries.pop(industry)
    }}
```

The current problem is when a checkbox is clicked, All of the items in the list get ticked although only the once which is clicked is saved. On untick, the item is removed from the list and all checkboxes become unticked. How do I tick and untick only the specific tickbox?

Comment: shouldn't you vary the input id attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same static `ng-model` for multiple check boxes, you need to either use a dynamic `ng-model` or one assigned to a value in the repeated array. This is so that each check box has its own separate model.

You can do this in multiple ways:

1. Add to your repeated array so that it has a value in each object in the array that says whether that object is selected or not. To do this you would assign it like `ng-model="industry.isSelected"`.
2. Have a separate object that stores the bool for whether each array object is selected. To do this you would assign it like so `ng-model="selection.industryIds[industry.id]"`

In your case the best option is likely the first one, you would also need to change the if statement to the following though:

```
vm.updateSelected = function (industry) {
    if (industry.isSelected) {
        vm.industries.push(industry)
    }
    else{
        vm.industries.pop(industry)
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ngModel helper](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

ngModel, input shoulde be string. Assignable AngularJS expression to data-bind to.

The name of AngularJS expression should be different.

`<input type="checkbox" id="industry-one" ng-model="ctrl.oneIndustry"/>`

`<input type="checkbox" id="industry-two" ng-model="ctrl.twoIndustry"/>`